# mp4 Resolution in android

Tags: android

Any one have idea what resolution android support.. what is the idle bit rate and Frame rate for android mp4 video...

Answer (score 1):

There are a plethora of android devices (60+) with different screen resolutions and decoding horsepower. There is not likely to be one right answer for this, the lower you keep your resolution the more devices will be able to play and the faster the experience will be even for the bigger devices esp if you are moving video across the network.

**Edit:** I think the lowest resolution screen on a production android device is 240×320 in the 2.8" screen on the HTC Tattoo.

Comment: my video resolution is  720*480 can it play in my emulator?

Comment: 720x is WAY too big for video on all but a few of the latest HD enabled special GPU powered devices. The phone in my pocket for example only has a 480x320 res screen, and that's still quite common and note even the smallest. Decoding that much video will also kill some weaker devices and EAT through battery even on the powerful ones. I don't know what your application is but seriously considering scaling that down, the general experience will be better.

Comment: Actually the throughput is mostly limited by macroblocks per second. The resolution is just secondary.